# ImportError on importing pycurl

Tags: python, curl, openssl, pycurl

I'm getting a traceback whenever trying to import pycurl, any help on solving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Version of Python is 2.7

```
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: symbol SSLv2_client_method, version     OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
```

Comment: openssl version is 1.0.1

Comment: It looks like OpenSSL was configured with `no-ssl2`. Rebuild the OpenSSL library *wihout* `no-ssl2` option (not recommended); or rebuild PyCurl against the version of OpenSSL you are using. Be sure to tell PyCurl that SSLv2 is not available. (If PyCurl is intelligent, it will see `OPENSSL_NO_SSL2` is defined in `<openssl/opensslconf.h>`).

Comment: Forgot to mention.... you can check for the symbol with `nm -D --defined-only /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 | grep -i SSLv2_client_method`. It should show up with a capital `T`, meaning its defined in the text section *and* its exported. But really, you don't want any of that SSLv2 (or SSLv3) crap... Its better to fix PyCurl.

Answer (score 2):

On debian for me helped this:

```
apt-get install -y libssl-dev
```